# issue with Setting delegate of viewcontoller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

I have two view controller A & B.From i am sending back some data to A view controller.My B `ViewController` is embedded in `NavigationController`. Now I am going to from A to B from below code.In this case my delegate method does not get called.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DropboxView", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav_drop") as! UINavigationController
let vc1:DropboxListingViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DropboxListingViewController") as! DropboxListingViewController
vc1.CTprotocolDelegate = self
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please suggest a better approach.

Comment: What do you mean your delegate method never gets called? Where are you attempting to call the delegate method?

Comment: In first view controller

Answer (score 1):

You need to access `DropboxListingViewController` from your `UINavigationController` object, in your case it is `vc` like this.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DropboxView", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav_drop") as! UINavigationController
if let vc1 = vc.viewControllers.first as? DropboxListingViewController {
    vc1.CTprotocolDelegate = self
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nirav D is correct.

Actually the problem with your code is that it is creating two instances of view controller 'DropboxListingViewController'. The instance in which you set your present view controller as delegate is actually never loaded in memory,instead the navigation controller creates its own instance of 'DropboxListingViewController',with which u have not registered yourself.
@deepak